# John arrived “in the Audi” or “by the Audi”?

Tags: prepositions

If I wanted to say that John returned back home in one of his cars, should I say:

> John arrived **in** the Audi!

Or

> John arrived **by** the Audi!

Or maybe there is a better way to express my thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"In the Audi" is the correct version, as he is in this specific vehicle. The "by" version is for a sentence like "John arrived by car", where you talk about the method he is arriving by.

Comment: *John arrived by Audi.*

Comment: Another possible way of expressing it would be "John arrived in his Audi"